# ios Horizontal UITableView inside another UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a button in horizontal UITableView inside another UITableView. When I tap a button application crashes with this message "unrecognized selector sent to instance". As I understand the problem is that another class handles tap but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You should post some code to hane more informations..

Comment: thx for your spent time but I've solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved. Maybe someone will need my solution. 
I moved

```
[self.checkBoxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

from view (actually this view is shown instead of cell

> [cell addSubview:CellView.view];

) 
to UITableView class to

> `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

and changed a little bit

> [CellView.checkBoxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

so, now tap handles not a view but uitableview class and everything works fine